# How to launch netbeans project after put the war file on tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, war, server-configuration

I had to archive the netbeans project in .war file. Then, put the war file on the server that used tomcat (tomcat/webapp). It is run successfully when I type in browser like http://localhost:8080/work. The next I need to do is I need to launch my netbeans project on real work as like when I type www.abc.com/work it can be work. Means that user can browse the url www.abc.com/work and do login process or something like that.

What I need to do to launch it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That means you want the tomcat uses the port 80 to listen to the HTTP protocol instead of the default 8080 .You can change it in `tomcat/conf/server.xml` :

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Then, people can access your tomcat 's web by `http://your.tomcat.ip.address/work`.

If you are inside the intranet , request your system admin to map your tomcat server 's ip to  `www.abc.com` in the DNS server such that  people can browse your web by `http://www.abc.com/work` .

If you are using the public ip , you can use some free dns provider such as [No-IP](http://www.no-ip.com) to map your IP address to `www.abc.com`

Comment: Yes, I use inside the intranet. Actually, the intranet already has 1 folder that I just need to put my project in there. But, it is not work properly. User just view the www.abc.com/work/login.html and when submit the login it appear http error 405. I had the database on server.What's wrong with that?

Comment: That 's mean you could access by using `www.abc.com/work/login.html` now but cannot submit the login in form as it returns http error 405? You could refer to http://dev-answers.blogspot.com/2008/06/http-status-405-http-method-post-is-not.html to see if the error 405 will be solved

Comment: The link that you give is for HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL. My error is 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.